# How to reference two columns from two different sheets in one query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I'm trying to write a query that looks compares strings within a cell on two different pages. This is the query I have written but it says unable to parse query string because there is no column b4.

```
=QUERY(Teams!B:F, "select F where B = B4", 0)
```

Note column B is on a different page than B4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if **B4** is number do:

```
=QUERY(Teams!B:F, "select F where B = "&B4, 0)
```

if **B4** is **not** number do:

```
=QUERY(Teams!B:F, "select F where B = '"&B4&"'", 0)
```

Comment: Sorry to ask what must be a silly question... The OP specifically refers to "two different pages/sheet", but the query refers only to the "Teams" sheet? To what does "B4" refer? A cell, a sheet, a range??

Comment: @Tedinoz as of my understanding OP has a spreadsheet with 2 sheets. one is called Teams and the other one is nameless (let's call it sheet1). so now OP is entering the query formula into sheet1 where he has a value in cell B4 so he could filter-down the Team sheet based on B4 value.

Comment: @Tedinoz sorry the B4 refers to the sheet I'm currently on so I didn't think I needed to reference the page since I was on it.

Comment: @player0 this worked thank you. Would you mind explaining the notation happening around the B4 variable?

Comment: @BaileyPeticolas notation depends on if the reference is a text string or numerical value. in a query, all text strings need to be surrounded with single quotation marks and be present within 2nd (string) parameter of query while numeric values can be standalone and be just appended with & after it